# The Identifier must be declared with a port mode : (for all 3 outputs) (Verilog)

Tags: verilog, comparator

I am getting three errors saying that the identifier must be declared with a port mode for my three output.  I cannot figure out why this is happening.  Some help would be great.

```
module Testbench (A2, B2, Zero, One, Two);
input [3:0] A2, B2;
output Zero1, One1, Two1;
wire e0, e1, e2, e3, A10, A11, A12, A13, B10, B11, B12, B13;
Compare  cp0(A2[0], B2[0], e0, A10, B0);
Compare  cp1(A2[1], B2[1], e1, A11, B1);
Compare  cp2(A2[2], B2[2], e2, A12, B12);
Compare  cp3(A2[3], B2[3], e3, A13, B13);
assign Zero = (e0 & e1 & e2 & e3);
assign One = (A13 | (A12 & e3) | (A11 & e3 & e2) | (A10 & e3 & e2 & e1));
assign Two = (~One & ~Zero);
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your port list, you have:

```
module Testbench (A2, B2, Zero, One, Two);
```

But you call out the outputs with different names:

```
output Zero1, One1, Two1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your port names and port declaration names do not match.

You could eliminate many of these types of errors where you have to declare names twice, sometimes 3 times, if you used Verilog-2001 syntax

```
module Testbench (
    input wire [3:0] A2, B2,
    output wire Zero, One, Two);
...
```